# Importing from sub class Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, arguments

Here is my python file called `Game_Factors`:

```
from Fesnoria_Game_Setup import Game_Setup

class Game_Events(Game_Setup):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Game_Events, self).game_setup(self.MAP_FILENAME, self.GS)
```

I am importing the class `Game_Setup` which contains the sub class `Setup`.

In the sub class `Setup` I have two variables, one called `self.MAP_FILENAME` and the other called `self.GS`, which I use as arguments when importing the `Game_Setup` class.

But when importing the `Game_Setup` class with the `self.MAP_FILENAME` and `self.GS` as arguments I get the error code:

```
AttributeError: 'Game_Factors' object has no attribute 'MAP_FILENAME'
```

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Game_Setup:

```
class Game_Setup(Setup):
    def __init__(self)
        super(Game_Setup, self).__init__()
```

Comment: no because `Setup` is a sub class of `Game_Setup` when I import them individually I get: `TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases Game_Setup, Setup`

Comment: Can you share a snippet of module in which you have `Game_Setup` written ?

Comment: there you go I put it up for you

Comment: You try to access an attribute before its creation.

Comment: so what should I do?

Comment: I need to call `super(Game_Events, self).game_setup(self.MAP_FILENAME, self.GS)`

Comment: super(Game_Events, self).__init__() for which class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def __init__(self):
        super(Game_Events, self).__init__()
        self.game_setup(self.MAP_FILENAME, self.GS)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat game_event.py 

from game_setup import Game_Setup

class Game_Event(Game_Setup):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Game_Event, self).__init__()

        print self.MAP_FILENAME

ge = Game_Event()

$ cat game_setup.py
from setup import Setup

class Game_Setup(Setup):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Game_Setup, self).__init__()


$ cat setup.py

class Setup(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.MAP_FILENAME = 'myfile.py'
        self.GS = 'GS'
```

Something like above.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you have described there, the reason is you don't have `self.MAP_FILENAME` and `self.GS` in scope in `__init__` inside `Game_Events` as they are defined in `__init__` of `Setup` superclass, which hasn't been called at this place. Constructors of superclasses are not called implicitly, so add a call to superclass's `__init__`:

```
from Fesnoria_Game_Setup import Game_Setup

class Game_Events(Game_Setup):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Game_Events, self).__init__()
        super(Game_Events, self).game_setup(self.MAP_FILENAME, self.GS)
```

This way it should work.

Note: If you decided to use `super(cls, self)`, use it consistently in your code or otherwise you might not get what you expect later in inheritance tree, because of how MRO works.